# Appinventor: How to send HTML code to webviewer?

Tags: app-inventor

I would like the downloaded html code to display as a website in my webviewer. Sending response to the WebViewers not working. (there is a real website under the name "mywebsite" ). Html code is downloaded normally (look on the 3 img) [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The webviewer goToUrl block is expecting a fully qualified domain name e.g.
https://www.google.co.uk. It must always start with an http[s]://.

If you want to download the source code of a site and then run it locally, you will need to save the source code to a file (.html), then load this as a local url.